# Can not connect to FTP server through FTPS (990), normal FTP (20,21) is OK

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I setup an FTP server on my Windows server, 
the default ftp protocol (20, 21) work well, I need it to work on TLS mode (990) but it's broken.

### Here is Local log

`Status: Connecting to 10.89.252.76:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (10,89,252,76,235,24)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing`

### Here is server log

`(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - (not logged in) (10.133.78.56)> Connected on port 21, sending welcome message...
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - (not logged in) (10.133.78.56)> 220-FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - (not logged in) (10.133.78.56)> 220-written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org)
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - (not logged in) (10.133.78.56)> 220 Please visit https://filezilla-project.org/
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - (not logged in) (10.133.78.56)> AUTH TLS
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - (not logged in) (10.133.78.56)> 234 Using authentication type TLS
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - (not logged in) (10.133.78.56)> TLS connection established
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - (not logged in) (10.133.78.56)> USER admin
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - (not logged in) (10.133.78.56)> 331 Password required for admin
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - (not logged in) (10.133.78.56)> PASS *****
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - admin (10.133.78.56)> 230 Logged on
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - admin (10.133.78.56)> PBSZ 0
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - admin (10.133.78.56)> 200 PBSZ=0
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - admin (10.133.78.56)> PROT P
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - admin (10.133.78.56)> 200 Protection level set to P
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - admin (10.133.78.56)> PWD
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - admin (10.133.78.56)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - admin (10.133.78.56)> TYPE I
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - admin (10.133.78.56)> 200 Type set to I
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - admin (10.133.78.56)> PASV
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - admin (10.133.78.56)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,89,252,76,203,166)
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:37 PM - admin (10.133.78.56)> MLSD
(000204)1/5/2019 16:30:47 PM - admin (10.133.78.56)> 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"`

I'm using FileZilla Server 0.9.60beta and Here is my setting and error log : 
[image: setting]
[image: connection setting]

Answer (score 3):

The log file you show is not from FTPS on port 990 (implicit TLS, i.e. from start) but clearly (first line of local log file!) from FTPS on port 21 (explicit TLS, TLS upgrade after `AUTH TLS` command).

So the setting of "Require **explicit** FTP over TLS" in your client (last image) is correct but the port should be 21 not 990. Alternatively you could use **implicit** FTP over TLS on port 990 which you seem to have enabled in the server too.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/longtth/666254b9d5698cbf13f9628eb133e43e

Comment: i've changed the explicit to implicit to get into 990, but still can't connect, can you help me have a look on it?

Comment: @Luke: that's a different issue now. The log says clearly that the connection succeeded but that it cannot transfer data: *"425 Can't open data connection"*. I have no idea of the setup of your server but my guess is that there is some firewall configured at the server which does not allow access to arbitrary ports - but this kind of access is needed with passive FTP.